# Is there a logical progression to application development?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am currently working on an application in WPF/C# for personal use. I am not a "classically trained" programmer. Simply a hobbyist that likes to code in his spare time. Is there any accepted approach to the progression of application development? I. E.; Make it work, add fault tolerance, create a gui, then performance optimization. Or maybe should I design the entire GUI first? Basically I am going to start a new project soon and would like to have some sort of "every program needs this" checklist.

Comment: Every program includes an email reader. Eventually.

Comment: @Adam Crossland: And a half-assed LISP implementation, for it to be really worth it. ;)

Comment: This would be a good community wiki question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really no "every program needs this" list, because there's absolutely nothing that *every* program needs.

Some advice, though: don't "make it work", then "add fault tolerance". Defensive programming and accounting for errors should be a continuing part of development. It's much simpler (and usually more effective) if you account for errors and unexpected input *when* you're writing a piece of code rather than after it's done.

As far as whether or not to make the GUI first, answer this question: is the most important aspect of the program *what it does* or *what it looks like*? That's a serious question that, honestly, can vary from application to application (though it's usually the former that's more important).

If functionality is more important, model your information in code and get some basic "business logic" (a term of art that represents the non-visual logic in the application that carries out the rules and operations that are fundamental to the purpose of the program) in place, then create a GUI that interacts well with it.

If the GUI is genuinely more important, create it first and model data objects and business logic around the GUI.

I would advise you to *peruse* [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_Development_Life_Cycle). It's pretty heady (as most technical Wikipedia articles are), but it provides some good links and will give you a rough idea of how the progression of software development and maintenance moves in the "real world".

Answer (score 1):

I'd say first of all, as simple as it sounds, write (either on paper or in your head) what the app is actually going to do. (Most businesses can't even do this part!)

Knowing that, sketch on paper what you think the screens will look like.
For example, say you're writing a home budget program and you want a drop down for accounts, and a grid for transactions, etc. Knowing what the GUI looks like will help tremendously.

Then fill in the details.

Answer (score 1):

If this is something you're doing as a hobby, you can choose any development methodology you want.

Typically, for commercial development, there's some form of prototype made first (for WPF, SketchFlow with Blend is fantastic for this).  This is typically required since you most often need to "sell" the concept, either to a client, management, etc.

However, if you're doing this on your own, you have the freedom to do things any way you wish.  One comment, however.  I would, personally, not thing of "fault tolerance" as separate from "making it work", however, since "fault tolerance" comes with testing, and unit testing as you go is much more effective...

Answer (score 0):

The development lifecycle varies a lot. Variance is due to project size, team size, timeline, etc...

For small hobby projects, I usually follow this approach:

1. Specs: this could be a half page typed about what I think I'm doing, and maybe some diagrams to make it more clear.
2. Plan: Usually a document where I outline what I think major milestones will be, such as "complete proof of concept", "basic gui", "system logging", "successful CRUD operations"
3. Code: Try to meet the first milestone in 2., then possibly re-evaluate 2. Continue until project is done, or I get bored / distracted by something else (usually shinier than whatever I'm working).

This last step may also involve sub-steps such as data modelling (if it's a database app) or graphics design for icons (if the GUI needs fancy icons).

Answer (score 0):

I try and take a look at my audience for the application.  Then I'll create some use cases where I try and figure out what and why my application should even be built.  Sometimes evaluating what you're writing and why you stumble across a lot of ideas that might shape the way you architect the application.

From there you can do as others suggest and put more importance on areas of focus.

Answer (score 0):

This is a huge topic that will probably garner a lot of opinions, so I'll chime in with this: Test-driven development. Try reading about it, and make the effort to incorporate it into your development strategy as soon as possible. TDD is the one thing I wish I had known when I started writing software years ago. It makes a world of difference in the quality of the stuff you put out.

Answer (score 0):

What has worked for me in the past is the following (high level) sequence:

1. Understand and record the requirements (who, what and when) - use-cases, feature list, flowcharts, service level requirements - whatever works for you (I am partial to use-cases though).
2. Understand and record the design (how) - class diagrams, sequence diagrams, screen designs, API specifications - start high level and drill down (could start development before complete drill down)
3. Implement - start with API/stubs and unit tests, then fill in the code, update unit tests and execute unit tests as you go.
4. System test - test the components operating together and fix defects.  Don't forget about performance testing (check that you have met your service level requirements from step 1).
5. Package, deploy and enjoy.